# How to stop my SSD "ejecting" from my iMac when in standby?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, imac, ssd, sleep-wake

I recently purchased an SSD drive for my 2009 27" iMac to replace the DVD Drive.

Everything installed fine, performance is good etc. *However* when the device (SSD) is put to "sleep", OS X sees it as ejected, and **will not** see it again until I pull the power from the iMac. Shutting down does not seem to help -- nor does restarting.

Things I've tried:

1. Reset the NVRAM -- after this it did show up without pulling the power, but then it disappeared again after going to slee[
2. resetting the SMC
3. Pulling the drive, and completely reseating it in case something wasn't quite installed right

None of which seemed to have helped. Support from the vendor suggested "Turn off sleeping of the hard disks". This seems poor since it leaves the HDD that is still in there spinning. Additionally, surely it's going to go to sleep when it goes to standby for the whole Mac.

Any suggestions/Thoughts?

Comment: If you go look at it in Disk Utility does it say it is Ejectable.

Comment: Nope -- sees it as non-ejectable & a solid state.

Answer (score -1):

have a look at:

http://www.mac-forums.com/apple-notebooks/273332-2nd-internal-hard-drive-ejects-sleep.html

It seems to be the caddy.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  Please don't post link-only answers as the content behind those links can change and make the answer invalid.  See here for how to write a good answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer  - From Review -